# Vue-CLI 3.5 windows + node.js process undefined - environment issue

Tags: vue.js, intellij-idea

This has nothing to do with Vue, this is tagged since anyone who started a project via the CLI on a windows machine would find this error. I am using the intelliJ IDE (PHPStorm).

in router build, I get process with a squigly red line saying it's undefined.

- I know that process is referring to a node process, can't understand how a js/ts variable would be defined, if it's not defined.
- Already visited https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes - after creating the `.env` file in root, nothing changed.
- My IDE is IntelliJ's PhPStorm, I have node coding assitance checked, but clearly this has nothing to do with this.

[image]

Can someone please explain to me how do I fix this properly?

> UPDATE: I downloaded `@types/node`, when I click on process in the image above I am actually reaching `@types\webpack-env\index.d.ts:338` stating: `declare var process: NodeJS.Process;` Yet with no effect on my IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to tell your IDE that it needs to look for `node` typings as well. Add this to your `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions`

```
"types": [
  "node"
],
```